# Collect data from MySql database to compare to variable

Tags: c#, mysql

i am basically building a multiple choice quiz where the user will receive a score based on their performance etc...
I am saving their score to a database for each individual different test on my site. I don't want to save their score if the score they receive on that particular pass of the multiple choice test is less that the value that is already assigned in the database. I need to be able to extract the score of the user currently in the database(Default score is 0 in my database table so there will always be a value), compare it to the score they have just received and if it is greater, save the new score into the database.

I cant work out how to extract just the users score and assign it to a variable so that i can compare the two. I am using the users id as the primary key in the table

So far i have the folowing:

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsValid)
        return;
    int score = 0;
    List<RadioButtonList> list = new List<RadioButtonList>() { RadioButtonList1, RadioButtonList2, RadioButtonList3, RadioButtonList4, RadioButtonList5, RadioButtonList6, RadioButtonList7, RadioButtonList8, RadioButtonList9, RadioButtonList10 };
    foreach (var element in list)
    {
        if (element.SelectedValue == "Correct")
        {
            score++;
        }

    }
    Response.Write("you scored: " + score);
    Button1.Visible = false;

    if (score != 0) ;
    {
        string UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        string MyConString = "SERVER=localhost;" +
        "DATABASE=synther_physics;" +
        "UID=root;" +
        "PASSWORD=rootpass;";
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);




        MySqlCommand commandPull = connection.CreateCommand();
        commandPull.CommandText = "SELECT score FROM userscores WHERE Id = UserID";
        int DBscore = 
        connection.Open();
        int RowsAffected = commandPull.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();



        if (DBscore < score) ;
        {
            Response.Write("New high score! Well done!");
            MySqlCommand commandReplace = connection.CreateCommand();
            commandReplace.CommandText = "REPLACE INTO userscores (Id, momentsandenergytestscore) VALUES (@Id,@score)";

            commandReplace.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", UserId);
            commandReplace.Parameters.AddWithValue("@score", score);

            connection.Open();
            int RowsAffectedReplace = commandReplace.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();

        }

        else;
        {
            Response.Write("You didnt beat your previous best of" + DBscore);
        }
    }
}
```

The part where i am actually trying to pull and compare the data is here(note the code is incomplete):

```
MySqlCommand commandPull = connection.CreateCommand();
commandPull.CommandText = "SELECT score FROM userscores WHERE Id = UserID";
DBscore = 
connection.Open();
int RowsAffected = commandPull.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ExecuteScalar`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-sql-command.html) to get the score:

```
int dbscore = (int)commandPull.ExecuteScalar();
```

> ExecuteScalar executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query.

Comment: Thankyou for the responce, I get an error when trying this: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Maybe the problem is here: `commandPull.CommandText = "SELECT score FROM userscores WHERE Id = UserID";`. You must change `UserId` for `@Id` and then `commandPull.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", UserId);`

Comment: is this a new line? before the defining of the variable DBscore?

Comment: like this?                 `MySqlCommand commandPull = connection.CreateCommand();
                commandPull.CommandText = "SELECT score FROM userscores WHERE Id = @Id";

                commandPull.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", UserId);
                int DBscore = (int)commandPull.ExecuteScalar();
                connection.Open();
                int RowsAffected = commandPull.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();`

Comment: You must open the connection before `ExecuteScalar`

Comment: yeah that was my mistake i didnt look clear enough at what you said about what it did as a command, ihave replaced that line and added the line with the parameter. I am now getting: `An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in ComputingProjectwh.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Specified cast is not valid.`                 At the point of the new command

Comment: Well,it depends on what type of data do you have in your database.

Comment: i am using the datatype varchar for both pieces of data?

Comment: Then,instead of casting to int,cast to string

Comment: Right got it all sorted, only final problem is that it is executing the following code even when the score in the database is greater that the users score